# Issue with TFTP when trying to Flash Aironet 1142N

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point, freebsd, tftp

I am having an interesting issue trying to flash (to convert an AP from lightweight to autonomous) Cisco Aironet 1142Ns

I have a small network setup with a computer serving as TFTP (FreeBSD 11) and console (minicom), a switch, and the APs.  The config is as follows:

- FreeBSD/TFTP:  10.0.0.2/255.0.0.0
- Cisco AP:  10.0.0.1/255.0.0.0

I have verified that the TFTP server is functioning; I connected a second computer and manually downloaded the Cisco firmware file from the TFTP server.  The command I issue is

```
$ tftp
tftp> connect 10.0.0.2
tftp> mode binary
tftp> get c1140-k9w7-tar.153-3.JB.tar
Received 9338880 byes during 4.6 seconds in 18241 blocks.
```

TFTP works.

I boot into "recovery" mode of the AP (hold down the mode button) until I get the `ap:` prompt.  I then issue the following commands:

```
ap:  set IP_ADDR 10.0.0.1
ap:  set NETMASK 255.0.0.0
ap:  set DEFAULT_ROUTER 10.0.0.2
ap:  tftp_init
ap:  ether_init
ap:  flash_init
Initializing Flash...
...The flash is already initialized.
```

(I don't get any messages with either `tftp_init` or `ether_init`)

When I issue the command to get the file, it times out:

```
ap: tar -xtract tftp://10.0.0.2/c1140-k9w7-tar.153-3.JB.tar flash:
tftp://10.0.0.2/c1140-k9w7-tar.153-3.JB.tar: connection timed out
```

**However...** if I allow the AP to boot and access it via the console, I am able to administer it and download the TFTP file and reflash it with an autonomous image.

So...why do I need to solve this?

1. The console keeps getting status messages that make it next to impossible to type and nothing I have found solves the issue
2. (and more importantly) I have a few APs with no boot firmware so the *only* way to flash them is via recovery.

Any assistance in solving why I cannot TFTP in recovery would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**  If I bypass the switch and go directly from my FreeBSD box to the AP, TFTP works.  I have tried this with 2 different switches (Netgear Gigabit, 3Com 10/100) and a no-name hub (yeah, still had one laying around).  The moment it's connected to the switch/hub, it fails, but direct, it works.  I would love to know why.

Comment: TFTP is an ancient protocol that originally had a file size limitation because it only had like a 16-bit counter of 512-byte blocks (or something like that). Some implementations worked around it by letting the counter wrap, and some worked around it by allowing larger blocks. You need to make sure your server and client implement the same workarounds. See if there’s a different TFTP server implementation you can use.

Comment: @Spiff - it's not the TFTP server, as I can xfer the file via TFTP when the AP boots its image.  If in recovery mode (image not booted), it won't even connect - the connection times out.

Comment: @Allen In my experience recovery mode codebases are drastically different from full booted OS codebases, so it’s not safe to assume they both use the same TFTP client code. Also, a “connection timeout” can just as easily come from failing to *complete* a connection in a timely manner as from failing to open a connection in a timely manner. Either way, a packet trace could clear this right up.

Comment: @Spiff - don't believe it's the code base, see my update.